# Use different arrangement for different displays with same brand on Mac

Tags: mac, display

I have 2 displays with same brand, I use one in the office and another at home. I would like to use different display arrangement settings for these 2 displays(both in extended mode, for the first one, I would like to see my macbook display on the left while for another the macbook is at the bottom), but it seems Mac OS thinks these 2 displays are the same one probably because they are the same brand, so whenever I changed the settings for any display, the other is also affected.